# Scala, Circe - how to check if json contains keys with different values?

Tags: json, scala, scala-cats, circe

I have a json which includes to similar fields:

```
{
  "newData": {
    "data": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": value2,
      "field3": "value3"
    }
  }
  "oldData" :{
    "data": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field3": "someValue"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to compare `newData` with `oldData`. If `newData` include some new fields which are not in `oldData` I want add them to `Set`. Also if `newData` and `oldData` have same field, but with different values I also want to add them to `Set`. If they are same I want to ignore.

I tried to do it with `circe` like this:

```
val newData = json.newData
val oldData = json.oldData
val result = newData.hcursor.keys.toSet
.filterNot(oldData.hcursor.keys.toSet)
```

And it works ok if `newData` have some other fields then `oldData`. But it does not work if both of them have same field with other values. I do not know how I could compare values of same key in both jsons and if they are different, add them to set.
How should I change my code to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that both are `JsonObjects` and then pick all the keys of the new record and check whenever that key existed in the old record or not, and if it did exist then ensure that its contents are different.

```scala
import io.circe.JsonObject

def findFieldsWithDifferences(oldData: JsonObject, newData: JsonObject): Set[String] =
  newData.toList.collect {
    case (newKey, newValue) if oldData(key = newKey).forall(_ != newValue) =>
      newKey
  }.toSet
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/5LlNRrsLQ0eMfJcsWDSJgw/3)*.

Comment: Yes, I parsed json to scala objects. And now I want to check if data from `newData` exist in `oldData` and if not add it to `Set`. Same thing if same fields exist in both, but have different values.

Comment: @Developus isn't that exactly what my code does? Or what did I miss?

Comment: The problem is `newData` and `oldData` are circe `Json`. I cannot call `toList` on it. thats why in my example I needed to look on keys.

Comment: @Developus yeah, just use `JsonObject` rather than `Json` like in the **Scastie** I linked.

Comment: But it is not as simple to convert from circe `Json` to `JsonObject`, isn't it? Would it be possible to do same thing just with `Json` type?

Comment: @Developus _"Would it be possible to do same thing just with Json type"_ not really, because keys are a concept that only apply to `JsonObjects`, not to any arbitrary **Json** value. - Second, why can't you just change from `Json` to `JsonObject`, if you are reading the data from a `String` you just need to adapt the decoder as shown in the **Scastie** - Finally, if you really can not read the data as a `JsonObject` then you can use the `Json.asObject` method that returns an `Option[JsonObject]`; check the [API](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html).

Comment: Ok, will try. But also I needed to change my Json structure and now `newData` and `oldData` include `data` object with all the values. Also, in you code `oldData(key = newKey)` this key cannot be recognize.

Comment: @Developus Was that the original shape of the data? Or did you made the change in order to fix the problem? Because if the latter, that was not needed, as you can see in the **Scastie** I used the original **Json** string you posted.

Comment: Yes, I changed it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233247/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-developus).

Comment: it wont work for nested json objects